# ЧПУ и mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

Приветствую.
Зачитался Гуглом и решил обратиться сюда. Есть ссылка вида: `domain/profile.php?param1=value1&param2=value2`
Нужно сделать ЧПУ вида: `domain/value1/value2`
Сделал при помощи генератора так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```

Кликаю по ссылке первого вида, ко второму виду ссылка не преобразовывается. Подозреваю, что в htaccess надо еще сделать правило редиректа на ссылку второго вида. Если верно, то как это реализовать?
И второе. Когда я руками вбиваю в строку браузера ссылку `domain/value1/value2` , то страница загружается, но без стилей. В чем тут может быть проблема?
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: По первому: htaccess вроде тут не нужен, обработывайте URL на стороне сервера. По второму почему стили не загружаются? Наверное потому что, что-то не так :)

Comment: Так вам нужно сделать статус 301, когда пользователь вбивает ссылку первого вида, а когда вторую - внутренне редиректить на первую?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```

И не забудь про

```
    <Directory "/...">
        ...
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```